# Table view function is dead-Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, tableview

I created a tvf in T-Sql that returns 28k records (Basically an insert and 7 updates - these updates use joins to tables in DB)

It takes 4 minutes which is not acceptable.

What I tried :

1. Take the code and run it from the query window -> 4 minutes
2. Change the @table to a #table and do a replace of @table to #table, run it from the query window - > 5 seconds

I read to avoid @tables with big tables ... is 28k records already big enough to make such a difference?

Or did I make obvious stupid mistakes?

Comment: Yes, 28k records is definitely enough to make this kind of difference. This issue comes from the fact that the frequently the query is compiled when the table variable is empty, and is not recompiled after it is filled, meaning the can be miles out. The execution plan for a table with 28k rows will mostly like be different from a table with 0 rows. Additionally SQL Server does not maintain column statistics for table variables, which can also mean that sub-optimal execution plans are chosen.

Comment: For futher reading, there is an excellent write up on the difference between temp tables and table variables over on[the dba site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/7257)

Comment: As it stands though, this question is more or less unanswerable. There may be various things that you could do within your TVF to optimise this, or you may be able to rewrite the TVF as a view, or inline function, but with no code posted, this is pure speculation.

Comment: Thanks - I could post the code - but I have rewritten this in a Stored procedure - and it's very fast now. What I am still wondering: Does that mean for me to avoiod TVFs unless I really only have a few records?

Comment: @EdwinEderle It will be better to use inline functions if you can - as such function can be easily joined. If the code is too complex - go to stored procedure. Anyway, in SQL Server 2017 and 2019 Microsoft introduce a series of performances optimizations for TVF, so it depends on the version, too.